# SQL Server, Entity Framework multiple dynamic connections string,

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am experiencing a mental block in searching/finding an example to this scenario.

**User-A logs on and connects to "master" database on "abcServer" to verify account.
Once approved, server returns connection string for "unique-A" database to user-A on "abcServer".**

I know the dbContext in EF has the constructor assigning a connString name, but I want this to be dynamic:

**(1) DbContext**

```
    // dbContext constructor
    public MasterDatabase() : base("name=MasterDatabase")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

**(2) The default connection is**

```
  // web.config
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MasterDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=abcServer;Initial      
        Catalog=Master;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But, that is it for the hard coding of connStr. The remainder of the project is about the respective user working with the EF classes in his/her db which won't be determined until return connection string from a successful login. Something like this:

**(3) Method in controller changing the conn string**

```
   // in api controller, once log in successful, call to method return value as parameter
   private void Connect2DbwithThisUsersConnString(string connStr)
    {
   // change the conn string & USE THIS CONTEXT to this user's db
    }
```

Any asp.net/mvc examples of this? Thanks in Advance. Going nuts here.

**Remember: I do not know the connection string until log in. This may be a new user, requiring a new database be created on the fly and that connStr passed along. I cannot hard-code a unique dbContext "base" or conn string.**

Many thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for entity Framework multi-tenancy with a per-user sharding approach.

You need two completely separate EF contexts. One, with a connection string in the conf files, to the login database. this context contains only login related objects/tables. After the login is validated the tenant specific location is retrieved from the login db (EF context) and the actual data is manipulated using a different EF context, that contain per tenant objects/tables. This context is opened using the appropriately constructed connection string. there are still many problems you'll have to solve, primarily on how to address the not trivial issue of schema changes and database upgrades (migrations).

You should also read about [Entity Framework and Federations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689720.aspx) for a different approach base don SQL Azure federations.

Comment: Remus, I do not want to use Azure. Any examples with stand-alone MsSql server? Sorry typo, any links on non azure examples?

Comment: My response is about non-azure versions. Only the final lines is suggesting the Federations as an alternative.

Comment: All users are sharing the same context, but in diff dbs. If I make changes to the classes, and migrations set to true, I fail to see the issue with schema changes and db upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult (if not impossible) to change a DbContext connection string after instantiating it.

You could make your `UniqueConnString` function return a new DbContext and create a new constructor in your `MasterDatabase` class accepting the connection string using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) constructor in DbContext

```
private MasterDatabase GetUniqueConnString(string connStr)
{
    return new MasterDatabase(connStr);
}


public MasterDatabase() : this("name=MasterDatabase")
{
}
public MasterDatabase(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
{
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me, does someone see an error or know a better way?**

```
// in controller/server //
private static void Init(string connStr)
 var connString = "Data Source=abcServer;Initial Catalog=" + dbName + ";Integrated Security=True;";
 var connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connString);
 var defaultContext = new DefaultDb(); //Context #1 - default connection from web.config
 var otherContext = new OtherDb(connBuilder.ToString()); //Context #2 dynamic connection
 ..... 
 }

// in OtherContext.cs //
     public partial class OtherContext
     {
         public OtherContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
     }

     public partial class OtherContext: DbContext   
     {
         public OtherContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection") { }
     }

    // the migration file //
     public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<OtherContext>
     {
         public Configuration()
         {
             AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
             AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
         }
     }
```